# Android Emulator Displaying Issue

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

Can Anybody tell me why is this happening in emulator i am using Android Studio Hedgehog, API 31 Android Version 12 for Emulator

tested on different emulators and API still the same try to downgrade it to giraffe but still the same issue. Can anybody help me on fixing this issue.

Thanks[Emulator Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyIEa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to solve the issue by downloading a new skin
i was not able to figure why the old skins were behaving like this, i downloaded  new skins of galaxy you can get it from the below link

https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin

this is the link for the tutorial on how to add them in your android emulator list
https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html

Note: If this does not work try upgrading or downgrading the API level i went from 30 to 27